# Table with Tags associations

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

So I have a table with tags and the videos they belong to. Both columns are primary.

[image]
..and so on

I need to make a list of the videos that have certain tags (multiple) associated with them.

So if I need all videos that have both tags 123 and 124, it would give me videos 14962 and 14963, etc.

I made the table structure assuming this would be easy, but have been staring at this for an hour and I'm still not seeing it.

Comment: I should mention this needs to scale up to n tags. Doesn't need to be fast at n tags, just work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These videos each have all 2 of those tags:

```
SELECT  video
    FROM  table
    WHERE  tag IN (123, 124)
    GROUP BY  video
    HAVING  COUNT(*) = 2 ;
```

These videos have *any 2 or more* of those tags:

```
SELECT  video
    FROM  table
    WHERE  tag IN (123, 124, 234)
    GROUP BY  video
    HAVING  COUNT(*) >= 2 ;
```

Example, using a similar dataset:

```
SELECT  state, GROUP_CONCAT(city)
    FROM  us
    WHERE  city IN ('Auburn', 'Fairfield', 'Lancaster')
    GROUP BY  state
    HAVING  count(*) >= 2;
+-------+----------------------------+
| state | GROUP_CONCAT(city)         |
+-------+----------------------------+
| AL    | Auburn,Fairfield           |
| CA    | Auburn,Fairfield,Lancaster |
| ME    | Auburn,Fairfield           |
| NY    | Auburn,Lancaster           |
| OH    | Fairfield,Lancaster        |
+-------+----------------------------+
```

You probably need a "derived table" (subquery) to get just a commalist of states:

```
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(state)
    FROM ( SELECT  state
            FROM  us
            WHERE  city IN ('Auburn', 'Fairfield', 'Lancaster')
            GROUP BY  state
            HAVING  count(*) >= 2 
         ) AS x;
+---------------------+
| GROUP_CONCAT(state) |
+---------------------+
| AL,CA,ME,NY,OH      |
+---------------------+
```

Or this:

```
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT state)
    FROM  us
    WHERE  city IN ('Auburn', 'Fairfield', 'Lancaster')
    GROUP BY  state
    HAVING  count(*) >= 2 
+------------------------------+
| GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT state) |
+------------------------------+
| AL                           |
| CA                           |
| ME                           |
| NY                           |
| OH                           |
+------------------------------+
```

Comment: Nice, simple, elegant. I wasn't aware of the HAVING command. This will help as I'll be able to rank videos based on how many tags it matches. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT group_concat(tag) AS tags
  FROM table
 WHERE tag IN (123,124,234)
 GROUP BY video 
 ORDER BY video
;
```

Comment: Some elaboration will surely help the OP...

Comment: This seems to give any video that is one of those tags. I need it to display only if it is all of those tags.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following will give you what you're after:

```
CREATE TABLE video_tag (vt_id INT PRIMARY KEY, tag_id INT, video_id INT);

INSERT INTO video_tag
VALUES (1, 14, 14959)
      ,(2, 45, 14959)
      ,(3, 116, 14960)
      ,(4, 7, 14960)
      ,(5, 76, 14960)
      ,(6, 18, 14960)
      ,(7, 33, 14960)
      ,(8, 95, 14960)
      ,(9, 120, 14961)
      ,(10, 123, 14961)
      ,(11, 114, 14961)
      ,(12, 8, 14961)
      ,(13, 16, 14962)
      ,(14, 124, 14962)
      ,(15, 123, 14962)
      ,(16, 124, 14963)
      ,(17, 123, 14963)
      ,(18, 44, 14963)
;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_tag_list (tag_id INT PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO temp_tag_list VALUES (123), (124);

SET @tagCount := (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM temp_tag_list);

SELECT video_id
  FROM (SELECT vt.video_id, COUNT(DISTINCT vt.tag_id) as tagCount
          FROM video_tag vt
                 INNER JOIN temp_tag_list tl ON (vt.tag_id = tl.tag_id)
         GROUP BY video_id
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT vt.tag_id) = @tagCount
       ) sq
;
```

You can see it work with this [db-fiddle link](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2arMKNmBoNn2ZDvQ535Gs7/2).

Here's how it works.

The first several lines simply create test data, based on the image in the original post; not actually part of the solution.

So, our first real step is to create a temporary table to hold our list of `tag_id`s we're searching for. I made `tag_id` a primary key merely to ensure the values in it are unique; things perform better that way.

Next, we save the count of tags we're searching for into a variable.

Finally, we run our actual query. The sub-query gets a count (for each `video_id` with at least one of the desired tags) of the total unique required tags found for that video. The `HAVING` clause says only keep rows where the count matches the total number of tags in the list - since the count is of the unique required tags, this just leaves the videos with all the tags. The outer query is simply to remove `tagCount` from the result set, so you just get the list of `video_id`s.